# event.preventDefault() always just before the end of the functions

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

In almost all the examples / templates scripts I can find, I see `event.preventDefault();` at the end of the function, like this:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

From my point of view, the idea is "stop immediately the default behavior then do whatever we have to do", like this:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: `stop immediately the default behavior` Events are put in queue so this doesn't make difference to put it at top or bottom of handler. But see TrueBlueAussie's answer, it usually more convenient to put it at bottom if for some reason you want to stop propagation too, using shorthand way `return false;`. That's said, i always put it at top just for readability but that's my own opinion

Comment: @A.Wolff   So to be clear, we don't run a risk of `event.preventDefault()` running 'too late' in this case? Can you elaborate what you meant by `Events are put in queue`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It makes no difference in the two specific examples shown. Put it where you like :)

The usual reason for having it at the end is when it replaces `return false;` as that was usually where the return had to be. `return false` is a shortcut for both `e.preventDefault()` *and* `e.stopPropagation()`.

The other thing to bear in mind is when you need to conditionally stop it, in which case the `preventDefault()` goes in the middle (of an `if` etc) :)